# Microsoft Excel VBA Plot Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA, I would like to create a macro that will plot a selected region prior to running the macro.  I have a macro that can plot the same data selection each time, but I would like it to plot a selection.  My current code is included below.  Thanks.

```
Sub AddChart()
'
' AddChart Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
'
 With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
            (Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B9")
        .Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to turn the currently `selected` cells into a chart, you can use Application.Selection.  When you have a cell or cells selected, Application.Selection will return a range value.  We can feed that directly into the source.

We check the `typeOf` to ensure that the current selection is a range to avoid any pesky errors.

```
Public Sub AddChart()
'
' AddChart Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
'

If TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
 With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
            (Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Application.Selection
        .Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood:

```
Sub AddChart()
'
' AddChart Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
'
Dim auxStr As String
auxStr = InputBox("Enter valid cell range, like A1:B9")
 With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
            (Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(auxStr)
        .Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
  End With
End Sub
```

You may add other variables too, for Left, Width, etc; all using the Inputbox. Of course, if you need to edit a lot of variables, a modal Userform will be easier to maintain and the right way to not allow wrong inputs.